# ReactJS not identifying touch/click on small screen

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a React App that is working absolutely fine on the Laptop Screen, but as soon as I reduce the screen size(after a certain point) the buttons stop working, the input fields stop working, and I can't even copy the paragraph text, it basically becomes an Image which I can Zoom In and Zoom Out from, nothing is clickable.
I am using Bootstrap4 + MD Bootstrap, directly the CSS files, not any npm package.
This is the code, **MyCustomRoutes** has a simple bootstrap form, with no rows or columns.

```
<div className="mt-4">
        <div className="row card-row">
                <div className="col-1 sol-sm-1 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div className="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <MyCustomRoutes />
                    </div>
                <div className="col-1 sol-sm-1 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

So I am not even getting the layout wrong, that it changes on smaller screen. Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks!

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Yep! Found it in the console. Thanks for the suggestion. Why did I not check in the console from the past few hours, I have no clue! :|

Comment: lol when i see similar issues it usually an error in the console

Comment: A lesson learned. The problem was in the Navbar code, and I didn't even think of checking that.

Comment: There might be nearby elements with higher z-indexes that overlap on small screens

Answer (score 0):

Is there a type on the class name string?

Should "col-1 **sol-sm-1** col-md-3 col-lg-4" be "col-1 **col-sm-1** col-md-3 col-lg-4"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Although, it was a problem in how the navbar was structured which I didn't think of even checking.